# Sending data to ES index using Logstash?

Tags: logstash

ES 2.4.1
Logstash 2.4.0

I am sending data to elasticsearch from local to create a index "pica".I used the below conf file.

```
input {
      file {
        path => "C:\Output\Receive.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => json_lines

      }
    }
    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200/"
        index => "pica"
    }
    stdout{
    codec => rubydebug
    }
    }
```

I couldn't see any output in either logstash prompt or in elasticsearch cluster.
When i seen the .sincedb file it has the following code:
`612384816-350504-4325376 0 0 3804`

May i know what's the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing out the square brackets **[]** for the `hosts` value, since it's a type of *array* as per the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-hosts). Hence it should look like:

```
elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]  
     index => "pica"
}
```

**OR** :

```
hosts => ["127.0.0.1"] OR hosts => ["localhost"]
```

Comment: It worked fine when i removed codec=>json_lines in the input may be the  problem is with my file content format i think so..Thanks